# Filter on boolean column

Tags: cassandra, cql

In the Apache Cassandra one needs a secondary index on a column to filter by. However a secondary index on a boolean column is an antipattern.

I have a collection of posts, each has a single tag (there are approx. 30 tags). One query is to show posts, that have a certain tag (it means that tag is a good candidate to the clustering key AFAIK).

There is also a logics that assigns a boolean "visibility" property to each post. Another query should show only visible posts, tag doesn't matter (ordered by timestamp descending).

How to model the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, tag would be a better candidate for a secondary index. If it is a clustering key, what is a partition key?

I would model this with 3 tables:

```
Table 1
Primary key:PostId 
Columns: Post Content
Table 2
Primary Key:  ( (timebucket), timestamp, visibility)
Columns:PostId
Table 3
Primary Key: Tag
Columns:PostId
```

Comment: This is a viable answer. Note, though, that you won't get both clustering ordering with the timestamp column AND boolean visibility filtering, so you'll filter the hidden/invisible posts manually on the application side.

Comment: OK. The recommendation is to use index tables that are maintained by my model. Since no one is interested in the invisible posts alone Table 2 would have the primary key ((timebucket), timestamp) and contain the IDs of visible posts only.

Comment: This solves the askers problem but does not answer to the question. How to query efficiently by boolean value?